# Trouble Converting .py to ,exe with auto-py-to-exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, auto-py-to-exe

I am new to python and tkinter, but I made a Hangman game that uses two external text documents to get words (easy and hard). I want to convert it to .exe but when I try to use auto-py-to-exe, after it finishes converting, the .exe always gives a fatal error. I have tried a variety of settings (one file, one directory, including the text documents as additional files, etc) but the same thing occurs everytime. Any suggestions for settings to use to make it work or other methods to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: "gives a fatal error" - what's the error? What's your code?

Comment: try converting it for console and get the error code

Comment: When I try to run the .exe, a window opens that says "Failed to execute script hangman.py". Does this help? I don't know how to identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you could do

```
file=open("./file.py","r")
content=file.read()
file.close()

file=open("./newfile.txt","w")
file.write(content)
file.close()
```

I think it will work

Have a nice day X)

Comment: could u explain what dis is ?

Comment: Yes of course : in python open means that you open a file : file=open("file","r"). The "r" means how you open your file : 'r' = read only, 'w' = write only. You can find a lot of documentation online here --> https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Comment: i mean how is this supposed to help here

Comment: This is not a real convertion, but you create a second file in .exe. You can then delete the first one (the .py) and you get the same result if you just convert your file. For deleting you can use --> `os.remove(file_to_remove)` and you get a nice and perfect convertion (same result).

Answer (score 0):

What works for me when converting .py to .exe with additional imports (like tkinter) is to add "hidden-imports", it's under the "advanced" tab when you are in auto-py-to-exe.

To get it to work, add "tkinter":

[image]